# QPaintDevice::height(): how to get max. height of screen?

Tags: qt

`QPaintDevice::height()` returns the height of the application window, not the height of monitor screen.

Ex: Assume a monitor screen that is 1920 pixels wide and 1024 high. If an app window is resized to 800 x 600, `QPaintDevice::height()` returns 600, not 1024.

What function must I call to get the 1024 value?

In Windows GDI, this would be `GetDeviceCaps(hdc, VERTRES)`

Comment: try with: `QGuiApplication::screens().at(0)->availableGeometry();`

Comment: BRILLIANT! Exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you  :o)